# unauthorized error when using JWT in Giraffe, F#

Tags: f#, jwt, f#-giraffe

I am using JWT(System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt) for authentication in Giraffe F#. I am successfully getting the JWT token, but when I use it on my API/tables route I get a 401 unauthorized response. I have tried to change the issuer and audience to http://localhost:5001 and http://localhost:5000 respectively that didn't work then I disabled ValidateAudience but didn't work either.

Here is my route:

```
open System
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors.Infrastructure
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting
open Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
open Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
open Giraffe
open backend.HttpHandlers
open System.Text
open Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer
open Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http
open JwtAuth
let authorize : HttpFunc -> HttpContext -> HttpFuncResult =
    requiresAuthentication (challenge JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)

let webApp =
    choose [ subRoute
                 "/api"
                 (choose [ POST
                           >=> choose [ route "/token" >=> Auth.handlePostToken
                                        route "/user/add"  >=> handleAddUser
                                        route "/table/create">=> handleAddTable
                                        route "/table/addData">=> authorize>=> handleAddTableData ]
                           GET
                           >=> choose [
                                        route "/tables">=> authorize>=> handleGetTableNames ] ])
             setStatusCode 404 >=> text "Not Found" ]

// ---------------------------------
// Error handler
// ---------------------------------

let errorHandler (ex: Exception) (logger: ILogger) =
    logger.LogError(ex, "An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.")

    clearResponse
    >=> setStatusCode 500
    >=> text ex.Message
```

Here is my config:

```
// ---------------------------------
// Config and Main
// ---------------------------------

let configureCors (builder: CorsPolicyBuilder) =
    builder
        .AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
    |> ignore

let configureApp (app: IApplicationBuilder) =
    let env =
        app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IWebHostEnvironment>()

    (match env.IsDevelopment() with
     | true -> app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage()
     | false ->
         app.UseCors(configureCors)
            .UseAuthentication()
            .UseGiraffeErrorHandler(errorHandler)
            .UseHttpsRedirection())
            .UseGiraffe(webApp)


let configureServices (services: IServiceCollection) =
    let sp = services.BuildServiceProvider()
    services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(fun options ->
            options.TokenValidationParameters <-
                TokenValidationParameters(
                    ValidateActor = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false,
                    ValidateLifetime = false,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = false,
                    ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:5001",
                    ValidAudience = "http://localhost:5000",
                    IssuerSigningKey = SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Auth.secret))
                ))|> ignore

    services.AddCors() |> ignore
    services.AddGiraffe() |> ignore

let configureLogging (builder: ILoggingBuilder) =
    builder.AddConsole().AddDebug() |> ignore

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    Host
        .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(fun webHostBuilder ->
            webHostBuilder
                .Configure(Action<IApplicationBuilder> configureApp)
                .ConfigureServices(configureServices)
                .ConfigureLogging(configureLogging)
            |> ignore)
        .Build()
        .Run()

    0
```

Here is the function I use to generate the token:

```
    let secret = "spadR2dre#u-ruBrE@TepA&*Uf@U"
  
    let generateToken email = 
        let claims = [|
            Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, email);
            Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Jti, Guid.NewGuid().ToString()) |]
        let expires = Nullable(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1.0))
        let notBefore = Nullable(DateTime.UtcNow)
        let securityKey = SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret))
        let signingCredentials = SigningCredentials(key = securityKey, algorithm = SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)

        let token =
            JwtSecurityToken(
                issuer = "http://localhost:5001",
                audience = "http://localhost:5000",
                claims = claims,
                expires = expires,
                notBefore = notBefore,
                signingCredentials = signingCredentials)

        let tokenResult = {
            Token = JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token)
        }

        tokenResult
```

I am using thunder client vscode to make the requests.

Comment: Do you have a GitHub repository we can use to reproduce what you're seeing?